# преобразовать txt в dictionary

Tags: c#, robots.txt, словари

есть несколько "txt" файлов, строка содержит название города, число – количество жителей в городе.

Как их преобразовать в  `Dictionary<string, int>`, что бы потом их соединить в один txt?
Может есть другой способ вместо dictionary?

```
string folderFile = @"C:\Users\Evgen\Desktop\TestIHS\DBTest"; //указали хранение файлов
string[] allFile = Directory.GetFiles(folderFile, "*.txt");

Dictionary<string, int> allTxt = File

//foreach (string s in allFile)
//{
//    try
//    {
//        allTxt.Add(allFile.);
//    }
//    finally { }
//}


//string allText = string.Empty;  //строка в которую можно только дописывать

//foreach (string s in allFile)
//{
//    try
//    {
//        allText += (File.ReadAllText(s).ToUpper());
//    }
//    catch (Exception e)
//    {
//        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
//    }
//}
//Console.WriteLine(allText);

//return allText;
```

Comment: цель, допустим есть 2(гомель, Гомель) города в разных или тех же тхт, они должны быть одним(сумма населения) городом, а потом только вывести в тхт

Comment: какой разделитель между названием города и числом жителей ? приведите пример одной строки

Comment: Вы просите парсить файлы, но делаете это не указав даже формат файла.

Comment: разделитель "," пример "минск, 50000 "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С использованием словаря, как вы и хотели

```
    string folderFile = @"C:\Users\Evgen\Desktop\TestIHS\DBTest";
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(folderFile, ".txt");

    Dictionary<string, string> all = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        foreach (var line in lines)
            all.Add(line.Split(',')[0], line.Split(',')[1]);
    }

    File.WriteAllLines("allFiles.txt", all.Select(x => x.Key + "," + x.Value ).ToArray());
```

Comment: а если каждая строка содержит только один город  с численностью и после нее нет "," а начинается новая строка?

Comment: Сплитить лучше один раз, а не два. При сохранении не нужно лишний раз материализовать всю коллекцию

Comment: @EvgeniyLyaschevsky тогда будет исключение, нужно добавить условие на существования второго значения

Comment: @АндрейNOP почему сплитить лучше один раз, а не два ? можете плз конструктивно ответить, я, вродь, тоже понимаю, что лучше не сплитить два раза, но не могу объяснить почему, по этому и не обращаю внимания на это

Comment: Ну как почему. Это метод, который манипулирует со строкой и создает массив. Это не бесплатно. А вы результат тут же выбрасываете и режете строку заново

Comment: @АндрейNOP логично, если щас не приучиться экономить память, то дальше будет только хуже ) спасибо

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд лучше сделать класс с двумя полями вместо словаря

```
      public class TestClass {
      public string City { get; set; }
      public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

Далее создаем List
читаем по очереди все файлы и добавляем в список.

Далее можно вывести весь список в одни файл или занести его в БД или создать xml файл

Comment: Вы говорите "лучше", но не приводите никакого обоснования. Возможно, вы забыли привести их или просто не любите готовить Dictionary, а зря. Могу предложить обратный вариант: Dictionary здесь лучше и могу объяснить: потому что нельзя ошибиться и добавив один файл дважды задублироваться.

Comment: Да наверное я не очень люблю Dictionary, но исходя из комментария автора, то в разных файлах может повториться город и нужно суммировать численность, поэтому все равно проводить проверку на то, что уже есть в списке (останется только предотвратить двойную загрузку одного и того же файла). А почему лучше - можно добавить поля (у города может быть много свойств, например страна), и есть города с одинаковым названием (например с названием "Москва" в мире есть аж 25 городов)